# Check for control characters

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, ravendb

I want to check a string to ensure it does not contain any control characters. I have come up with this solution. Would you agree it is adequate for the intended purpose? Is there anything obvious I'm missing out?

```
        string input = "2cancer＇.pdf";

        char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();

        foreach (var c in chars)
        {
            if(c == 127 || (c < ' ' && c != '\t'))
            {
                throw new Exception("Control character detected");
            }
        }
```

The background to this is an issue with uploading a file into RavenDB, it is complaining that the file name contains an invalid control character namely ＇, so I was hoping to detect the invalid control character and either remove it or throw an exception to alert the user, although I'll probably be doing the former.

The stack trace for the exception is:

```
    [ArgumentException: Specified value has invalid Control characters.
    Parameter name: value]
       System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.CheckBadChars(String name, Boolean isHeaderValue) +8426470
       System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Set(String name, String value) +86
       Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.WriteMetadata(RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:573
       Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest..ctor(CreateHttpJsonRequestParams requestParams, HttpJsonRequestFactory factory) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:91
       Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequestFactory.CreateHttpJsonRequest(CreateHttpJsonRequestParams createHttpJsonRequestParams) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequestFactory.cs:57
       Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectPutAttachment(String key, RavenJObject metadata, Nullable`1 etag, Stream data, String operationUrl) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:490
       Raven.Client.Connection.<>c__DisplayClass19.<PutAttachment>b__18(String operationUrl) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:441
       Raven.Client.Connection.<>c__DisplayClassa.<ExecuteWithReplication>b__9(String operationUrl) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:167
       Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.TryOperation(Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs:564
       Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.ExecuteWithReplication(String method, String primaryUrl, Int32 currentRequest, Int32 currentReadStripingBase, Func`2 operation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs:523
       Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication(String method, Func`2 operation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:174
```

I am aware this is a bug in the version of RavenDB I'm using, however at this moment it is not possible for me to upgrade the database.

Comment: As an aside, `string` implements` `IEnumerable<char>`, so you could actually do `foreach (var c in input)`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Char.IsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if a character is a control character.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Ta

Comment: This could simplify your check to `input.Any(char.IsControl)`

Answer (score 2):

```
    string input = "2cancer＇.pdf";

    char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();

    foreach (var c in chars)
    {
        if (char.IsPunctuation(c) || char.IsSymbol(c) || char.IsControl(c))
        {
            throw new Exception("Control character detected");
        }
    }
```